# Larave, print all columns from a query result

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am building a tool to allow users to view different content from the database.

The data returned by the server may has different columns every time (depending on a url parametrs).

I want to print all the columns available on every row of the `$data` array whatever they are.

I tried the following code but this doesn't work as I expected it just show 1's on the first three columns.

```
<tbody>
        @foreach($data as $aRow)
          <tr>
              @foreach($aRow as $aField)
                <td> {{$aField}} </td>
              @endforeach
          </tr>
         @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

Is there any way to achieve this without sending columns names along with the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that your $aRow is returning a Model object. Then in your second foreach I believe you can use ($aRow->toArray() as $column => $aField)

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($data as $aRow)
      <tr>
          @foreach($aRow->toArray() as $column => $aField)
            <td> {{ $column }} </td>
            <td> {{ $aField }} </td>
          @endforeach
      </tr>
     @endforeach
```